# How to set lockscreen password timeout on KDE longer than 5 mins?

Tags: linux, passwords, kde, plasma-tv

Settings > Workspace Behavior > Screen Locking
It's not possible to set "Allow unlocking without password for" to more than 5 minutes here. Is it possible to increase this value somehow?

Answer (score 0):

The same problem is addressed in the post
[Screen Locking: Allow unlocking without password for: always?](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/i02n3o/screen_locking_allow_unlocking_without_password/)

This answer comes from the post :

> Screensavers have not been deprecated, they are just not included in
> KDE's System Settings anymore. If you want a screensaver install
> xscreensaver and configure it like you always have. I still have
> xscreensaver on my machine and it works just like it always did. You
> can set the xscreensaver not to lock for up to 720 minutes (12 hrs),
> or just don't check the locking box in the settings and it will
> display but not lock.
>
> If you like xscreensaver you may want to install the rss-glx pack
> which includes most of the better looking screensaver implementations
> that are available for linux. You will probably want to set
> xscreensaver to load automatically at startup.
>
> I too would like it if the settings were still included in the KDE
> System Settings, but it is gone and it isn't coming back any time
> soon. Depending on which distro you are running there may be several
> different versions of xscreensaver available with distro specific
> themes and such.
>
> KDE screen locker leaves a lot to be desired and the devs have stated
> explicitly that this is the way it is going to be for the foreseeable
> future. This seems to be contrary to KDE's usual policy of giving us
> every possible control, but they must have their reasons.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. Xscreensaver is not an alternative because it is not well integrated into KDE, it requires a lot of hacks to decently work in every scenario, if it's even possible. I'm fine with the built-in solution, I would like to use that. My only problem is the short password timeout.

Comment: I don't know of a way to force a larger timeout without using xscreensaver, and you're not the first to ask about it.